# How to testfor what block an arrow ran into

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a system that changes the block and arrow ran into. So far I've made the system that changes the block, kills the arrow, and ONLY the arrow that ran into the block, using blockdata I can change the block below or above easily but not all around. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a problem, but instead you want us to offer you a solution. Don't think this is the right place to ask for that.

Comment: You would have to somehow test if three of the four positions 0.1 blocks in each direction are the same, but I currently can't think of a good way to do that.

Comment: The arrow does actually save the block it's in: minecraft.gamepedia.com/chunk_format So you can get the type at least. And if it's a block entity, you can also get x, y and z, but putting those into coordinates is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer for **1.13 snapshots**, which you should be using anyway so that your work won't be undone when 1.13 comes out soon! (Commands are pretty much rewritten in 1.13)

What you want to do is get the xTile, yTile, and zTile NBT values of the arrow with NBT of `inGround:1b`, then teleport an invisible entity (such as a `NoAI:1,Invulnerable:1,Silent:1` area_effect_cloud which is commonly used for marking things), and set it to those coordinates. You can do this in the 1.13 snapshots using the `execute store` and `data get` commands: `execute as @e[type=area_effect_cloud,name=whatever_you_want] store result entity @s Pos[0] double 1 run data get entity @e[type=arrow,limit=1] xTile 1`, then do the same for `Pos[1]` and `yTile`, and `Pos[2]` and `zTile`. Then, have that invisible entity set a block at its location and afterwards kill that entity. Done!

Recap:

1. If the arrow is in the ground (has NBT `inGround:1b`), summon an invisible entity as a marker
2. Set the `Pos[]` NBT tags of the marker entity as the `xTile`, `yTile`, and `zTile` of the arrow
3. Have the marker entity set the block at its location to whatever you want
4. Kill the entity

Sorry for the long explanation, but you can't just have the arrow set a block at it's location because the arrow's position is always outside of the block that it's stuck in.

If you're set on using 1.12, I don't think there's a good way to do this. I couldn't find anything easily on google, but some further searching might turn up something.